# Should _post data from buttons be sanitized?

Tags: php, security

When working with get() data, or data input from the users, im aware that you should never trust the input, and always make sure to sanitize the data before you use it in mysql queries or stuff like that.

But what about when its not user input? Like if you have a radiobutton with 3 different inputs, and a few hidden fields, and you send it with POST? Should you still sanitize the data you get from the $_POST, or is it secure? Because you know the values that you should get, as you set the values of the radiobutton and the hidden fields yourself?

I have build my script so that i always sanitize the data, but i was wondering if it was secure without sanitizing, as you really dont get any use input?

Comment: The values can be changed by the user - sanitize EVERYTHING!

Comment: If it comes from outside your system, it must be treated as potentially hostile/malicious. Doesn't matter HOW it gets to your system, or WHERE it's coming from. Outside data is dangerous.

Comment: *Anyone* can send *any* request to your server. It’s the server’s responsibility to process the data properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should sanitize anyway, as someone could modify the HTML before submitting the form.

On newer browsers you can right-click -> inspect element, which allows users to modify the HTML page as they see fit, they could modify your hidden fields or select values as they see fit.

Here is another thread on the subject : [Are drop down select fields vulnerable to any sort of injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008017/are-drop-down-select-fields-vulnerable-to-any-sort-of-injection)

Note : Use prepared statements for all your queries, this is a good habit to take and will ensure your queries are always sanitized.

Comment: Using prepared statements is something i will look further into, as it seems this is the best way to prevent injections. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Always sanitize

Anyone can edit the form HTML and insert naughty code (even in your radio button)